# add own php contact form to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contacts

i created a website and i'm just beginning with content management, so i installed wordpress with xampp and now adding everything that i made to the wordpress server. the only problem that came up is that i have a regular html formular with an action added that starts the php file when the user sends me the email which works offline. now i copied everything over and i don't get anything. it just sends me to another page without any content in it. so now my question is how do i tell wordpress to start the php file, when the user clicks on submit, send me the email and redirect the user to a success page.

Comment: Have you created a Template for Success page ?

Comment: nope and if its easier without the success page i don't need to have one. i just hope there is a fix for the bigger problem that it actually sends the email

Comment: Just echo the success message after you successfully send the mail on the same page where you have your own html form.
You don't have to create any template then

Comment: alright so i just add the echo to the mail.php and then everything works?

Comment: It needs some conditions then it should work like the way you want..

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the submit value and send the email:

A simple form:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="some_field">
    <input type="submit" name="sendmail" value="1">
</form>
```

Add this to your functions.php:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['sendmail'] ) ) {

    // here the code to send the mail
    wp_mail( ... );

    // redirect to a specific page
    wp_redirect( site_url('email-confirm') );
    exit;
}
```

Usefull links: [wp_mail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/), [wp_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/)

Comment: i just get a 404 page right now this is my code for the form and the php

Comment: Look at my comment to your answer.